# Plot regression confidence interval using seaborn.objects interface (v0.12)

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, scatter-plot, seaborn-0.12.x

How can I use the `objects` API to plot a regression line with confidence limits (like [`sns.regplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.regplot.html) / [`sns.lmplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lmplot.html))?

Based on the [`so.Band`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.objects.Band.html) `fmri` example, I thought it would be something like this:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import seaborn.objects as so

df = sns.load_dataset("tips")

(so.Plot(df, x="total_bill", y="tip")
   .add(so.Dots())
   .add(so.Line(), so.PolyFit()) # regression line
   .add(so.Band(), so.Est())     # confidence band
)
```

But I'm getting an unexpected result (left). I'm expecting something like the `regplot` band (right).

[image: current and expected output]

Comment: **Band: The mark fills between pairs of data points to show an interval on the value axis** it appears that bands are only drawn when the value on the x-axis has more than one value on the y-axis. There are only 14 total_bill values that repeat `tips.total_bill.value_counts().head(15)`, and that's where the bands are drawn. Compared to `fmri` in the documents, where each x-axis value has 56 corresponding y-values.

Comment: `Band` would be the correct mark here however `Est` is not the correct stat, because it computes aggregates to a point estimate + error at each unique `orient` value.

Comment: @mwaskom correct me if this is not correct. The ci band in lmplot and regplot **is estimated using a bootstrap** of up to 100 points. This does not appear to be the case with Band.

Comment: `Band` is a mark, it doesn't do any estimation one way or the other.

Comment: @mwaskom Which stat should be used here instead of `Est`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`seaborn.object` **can only aggregate provided data** (e.g. key/value pairs for histograms). Your use-case is more complex, and you **need to create bootstrapped regression data yourself**. Other APIs are capable of doing this on the fly, but `object` can not as of now (see the note).

Consider this code preparing bootstrapped predictions

```py
import seaborn as sns
import seaborn.objects as so
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.ensemble import BaggingRegressor

# data
df = sns.load_dataset("tips")

# bootstrap regression: tip ~ bill
X = df['total_bill'].values.reshape(-1,1)
y = df['tip'].values
model = BaggingRegressor(LinearRegression(),
                         n_estimators=100,
                         max_samples=1.0, # 100% of the dataset
                         bootstrap=True)

model.fit(X, y)
bootstrapped_preds = pd.DataFrame([m.predict(X) for m in model.estimators_]).T

# combine bootstrapped preds and original data
df_pred = pd.concat([df[['total_bill']], pd.DataFrame(bootstrapped_preds)], axis=1)
df_pred = pd.melt(df_pred, id_vars='total_bill', value_vars=list(range(50)), value_name='tip')
df_pred['type'] = 'pred'
df_pred = pd.concat([df_pred,df[['total_bill','tip']]],axis=0)
df_pred['type'] = df_pred['type'].fillna('observed')
```

and this one plotting 2 x standard deviation around predictions.

```py
# plot
import seaborn as sns
import seaborn.objects as so

(so.Plot(df_pred, x="total_bill", y="tip", color="type")
    .add(so.Band(), so.Est(errorbar=('sd',2), n_boot=1000))
    .add(so.Dot(), so.Agg())
)
```

which generates this figure
[image]

And here is [the full notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/maciejskorski/f613c38af891d49c7f8fb0e97a8b6332/seaborn_regression_ci.ipynb).

---

Seaborn's **object API is unmature** as of now (although very interesting!) and does not support some requested functionalities yet. The maintainers also [**don't accept some PRs going too far**](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/pull/3261), promising more features once the code stabilizes. Quoting the git discussion (Feb'23):

> I believe PolyFit is basically a placeholder now, to provide basic functionality, but may change in the future, which is why the doc is incomplete.
> As for having more objects, I think the answer is in #3133 : it is
> definitely intended to have more objects, but probably once the API is
> more stable. Adding the objects now would mean more maintenance and
> discourage changing the API when it may be necessary. Having them in
> the Discussions seems a good compromise to me : accessible to other
> users, but without the pressure of maintenance.

My advice is to not try to find hacks, but simply use the standard API and keep thumbs up for improvements in future releases of `seaborn.objects`.

Comment: The paragraph you quoted was a response to someone who asked about documenting the usage of `Line`+`PolyFit` and about adding other `Line` objects, so it doesn’t seem directly related to my `Band`+`Stat` question. It’s definitely possible that this `Band`+`Stat` functionality has also not been implemented yet, but I don’t think this quote confirms that.

Comment: The confusion comes from the fact that `Band+Stat` need to operate on the dataframe. You expect them to somehow interact with the regression which is too much. But you can compute bootstrapped predictions yourself, and then it works. See the revised answer.